# Passing a constant to fminsearch

Tags: matlab, fminsearch

How can I pass a constant to fminsearch?  So like, if I have a function:

f(x,y,z), how can I do an fminsearch with a fixed value of x?

```
fminsearch(@f, [0,0,0]);
```

I know I can write a new function and do an fminsearch on it:

```
function returnValue = f2(y, z)

returnValue = f(5, y, z);

...

fminsearch(@f2, [0,0]);
```

My requirement, is I need to do this without defining a new function.  Thanks!!!

Comment: surprisingly low-rated question. Is there a duplicate somewhere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use anonymous functions:

```
fminsearch(@(x) f(5,x) , [0,0]);
```

Also you can use nested functions:

```
function MainFunc()
    z = 1;
    res = fminsearch(@f2, [0,0]);

    function out = f2(x,y)
        out = f(x,y,z);
    end
end
```

You can also use `getappdata` to pass around data.

Comment: Thanks, this is the method I used.

Comment: This answer with additional examples is actually included in the official matlab documentation:
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/parameterizing-functions.html

Answer (score 2):

One way I can think of is using a global variable to send the constant value to he function, this is in the level of the function you use. For example

in your function file

```
 function  y  = f(x1,x2,x3)
 % say you pass only two variables and want to leave x3 const
 if nargin < 3
     global x3
 end
 ...
```

then in the file you use fminsearch you can either write

```
    y=fminsearch(@f,[1 0 0]);
```

or

```
 global x3
 x3=100 ; % some const
 y=fminsearch(@f,[1 0]);
```

It would be interesting to see other ways, as I'm sure there can be more ways to do this.