# Octave fminsearch: Problems with minimization and options

Tags: matlab, octave

I am trying to use Octave's fminsearch function, which I have used in MATLAB before. The function seems not sufficiently documented (for me at least), and I have no idea how to set to options such that it would actually minimize.

I tried fitting a very simple exponential function using the code at the end of this message. I want the following:
I want the function to take as input the x- and y-values, just like MATLAB would do.  Furthermore, I want some control over the options, to make sure that it actually minimizes (i.e. to a minimum!).
Of course, in the end I want to fit functions that are more complicated than exponential, but I want to be able to fit exponentials at least.

I have several problems with fminsearch:

1. I tried handing over the x- and y-value to the function, but a matlab-style thing like this:

   ```
   [xx,fval]=fminsearch(@exponential,[1000 1],x,y);
   ```

   or

   ```
   [xx,fval]=fminsearch(@exponential,[33000 1],options,x,y)
   ```

   produces errors:

   > error: options(6) does not correspond to known algorithm
   >   error: called from:
   >   error:   /opt/local/share/octave/packages/optim-1.0.6/fmins.m at line 72, column 16
   >   error:   /opt/local/share/octave/packages/optim-1.0.6/fminsearch.m at line 29, column 4

   Or, respectively (for the second case above):

   > error: `x' undefined near line 4 column 3
   >   error: called from:
   >   error:   /Users/paul/exponential.m at line 4, column 2
   >   error:   /opt/local/share/octave/packages/optim-1.0.6/nmsmax.m at line 63, column 6
   >   error:   /opt/local/share/octave/packages/optim-1.0.6/fmins.m at line 77, column 9
   >   error:   /opt/local/share/octave/packages/optim-1.0.6/fminsearch.m at line 29, column 4

   Apparently, the order of arguments that `fminsearch` takes is different from the one in MATLAB. So, how is this order??
   How can I make `fminsearch` take values and options?
2. I found a workaround to the problem that the function would not take values: I defined the x- and y values as global.  Not elegant, but at least then the values are available in the function.
   Nonetheless, `fminsearch` does not minimize properly.
   This is shown below:

   Here is the function:

   ```
   function f=exponential(coeff)
   global x
   global y
   X=x;
   Y=y;
   a= coeff(1);
   b= coeff(2);
   Y_fun = a .* exp(-X.*b);
   DIFF = Y_fun - Y; 
   SQ_DIFF = DIFF.^2;

   f=sum(SQ_DIFF);
   end
   ```

   Here is the code:

   ```
   global x
   global y
   x=[0:1:200];
   y=4930*exp(-0.0454*x);
   options(10)=10000000;
   [cc,fval]=fminsearch(@exponential,[5000 0.01])
   ```

   This is the output:

   > cc =
   >
   > 4930.0   5184.6
   >
   > fval =  2.5571e+08

   Why does `fminsearch` not find the solution?

Comment: This might be interesting for you - how to avoid globals : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12874317/passing-a-constant-to-fminsearch

Answer (score 1):

The optimization function `fminsearch` will *always* try to find a minimum, no matter what the options are. So if you are finding it's not finding a minimum, it's because it failed to do so.

From the code you provide, I cannot determine what goes wrong. The solution with the globals should work, and indeed *does* work over here, so something else on your side must be going awry. (NOTE: I do use MATLAB, not Octave, so those two functions could be slightly different...)

Anyway, why not do it like this?

```
function f = exponential(coeff)

    x = 0:1:200;
    y = 4930*exp(-0.0454*x);

    a = coeff(1);
    b = coeff(2);

    Y_fun = a .* exp(-x.*b);     

    f = sum((Y_fun-y).^2);
end
```

Or, if you must pass `x` and `y` as external parameters,

```
x = [0:1:200];
y = 4930*exp(-0.0454*x);
[cc,fval] = fminsearch(@(c)exponential(c,x,y),[5000 0.01])


function f = exponential(coeff,x,y)

    a = coeff(1);
    b = coeff(2);

    Y_fun = a .* exp(-x.*b);     

    f = sum((Y_fun-y).^2);

end
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an fminsearch implementation in the octave-forge package "optim".
You can see in its implementation file that the third parameter is always an options vector, the fourth is always a grad vector, so your ,x,y invocations will not work.

You can also see in the implementation that it calls an fmins implementation.

The documentation of that fmins implementation states:

```
         if options(6)==0 && options(5)==0 - regular simplex
         if options(6)==0 && options(5)==1 - right-angled simplex
            Comment: the default is set to "right-angled simplex".
              this works better for me on a broad range of problems,
              although the default in nmsmax is "regular simplex"
```

A recent problem of mine would solve fine with matlab's fminsearch, but not with this octave-forge implementation. I had to specify an options vector [0 1e-3 0 0 0 0] to have it use a regular simplex instead of a 'right-angled simplex'. The octave default makes no sense if your coefficients differ vastly in scale.